# Как ловить перемещение курсора на смартфонах?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Явный пример - мобильная версия ВКонтакте. Если в браузере провести пальцем слева на право, то откроется меню (на Android, не знаю как на остальных..). Как считывать такие передвижения? Например можно ли такое на jQuery запилить? Если провели слева на право, то добавляем класс какой-нибудь, куда-нибудь, например.

Comment: Первое, что приходит в голову - [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/), ([статья на хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/132947/))

Comment: Да, мне тоже. Сейчас как раз изучаю

Comment: Поищите в гугле события tap, starttap и тому подобное. В смартфонах нет понятия курсора, на сколько я знаю.

Comment: Я понимаю, что нет. Надо же как то объяснить суть вопроса))

Comment: > Поищите в гугле события tap, starttap
> и тому подобное. В смартфонах нет
> понятия курсора, на сколько я знаю.

интересно а как определяется дигитайзер(стилус такой) на самсунгах note? интересно а как определяется дигитайзер(стилус такой) на самсунгах note?

Comment: Наврятли в браузерах реализовано что-то специальное для дигитайзера. Должно быть такое же 'tap'. Хотя я точно не знаю. Не задавался еще таким вопросом никогда.

Comment: Очень кстати зашел я на хабр: http://habrahabr.ru/company/mailru/blog/165213/

Comment: ПО моему, ты сам нашел ответ на свой вопрос.